# (JavaScript) How can I manipulate the vertices of the sphere in three.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, three.js, 3d, geometry

I am just starting out with programming and getting started with my own projects. I am working with three.js for this particular project to get an interactive sphere.

I did create the sphere and made it interactive through orbital controls so I can move the sphere little bit like google earth.

What I'm trying to know is maybe very simple for a lot of people so I hope someone can help.

I want to convert all the vertices on the sphere into their own objects so that I can program them differently and interact with them. 
An example of this can be like when we click on a place on google earth then it zooms in and opens up a window giving details about that particular city. 
And in my project, I will like that if I click on a vertice then it changes color around that area for that and surrounding vertices, if I can get to that point then I'll be able to learn more on my own. Any guidance in the right direction will help.

Comment: Take a look at the source of this example - https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_points.html

It's not exactly what you want but some of the concepts you talk about are in this example, to at least to start thinking about.

Comment: This question was also [posted here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-can-i-manipulate-the-vertices-of-the-sphere-in-three-js/12806/3) on the three.js forum.